# How to CONVERT/CAST a column in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

can someone help with this. I'm having a problem with this sql query.
I need to convert price1_split to int. But it seems it also gets the concatenation i made beside it.

```
SELECT product_number,product_name,description,
price1+ ' ' + CONVERT(INT, price1_split) + '% |' + 
price2+ ' ' + CONVERT(INT, price2_split) + '% |' + 
price3+ ' ' + CONVERT(INT, price3_split) + '%'  as price_split
from tbl_products
```

error msg says:
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '% |' to data type int.

Comment: what is the type of price_split? If it is VARCHAR you don't need to cast and if it is Numeric, you would not cast to INT but VARCHAR

Comment: the string `' '` + the integer `price1_split` results in integer price1_split (the `' '` space is ignored).  however, when you then try to `+ '% |'` SQL Server doesn't know what to do because you can't add a string to an integer, and you get the error.

Comment: hi tcoder & KM, i appreciate your help.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you ultimately need a string value separated by `% |`, you should not be casting these to integers at all.  You would need to cast them to INT if you were adding the values together, but you are not adding them, you're concatenating them onto strings.  Assuming they are already string (`CHAR, VARCHAR`) values, just concatenate them onto the other character elements.

```
SELECT product_number,product_name,description,
  price1+ ' ' + price1_split + '% |' + 
  price2+ ' ' + price2_split + '% |' + 
  price3+ ' ' + price3_split + '%'  as price_split
from tbl_products
```

If however, they are float values you are trying to truncate to integers, you can `CONVERT()` them to `INT` and then `CONVERT()` them back to strings to concatenate.  In this case, it would probably be better to use `FLOOR()` for the truncation as in  `CONVERT(VARCHAR(n), FLOOR(price1_split))`

```
-- Using CONVERT(INT) for truncation
SELECT product_number,product_name,description,
  price1+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(INT, price1_split)) + '% |' + 
  price2+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(INT, price2_split)) + '% |' + 
  price3+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(INT, price3_split)) + '%'  as price_split
from tbl_products
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, your solution works! Can i call you master :)